# Rails trying to save form with collection_select that is empty gives undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with a drop down generated from a collection_select. The collection_select starts off blank and then when the user selects a date from the date field, the collection_select is updated with values for the date that is chosen.

I'm trying to show a nice error message if the form is submitted without a value chosen in my dropdown. Currently i'm getting this error: `undefined method`map' for nil:NilClass`

How can i make it so that if the user doesn't select a value in the dropdown, I can show them a nice error message?

View

```
<%= form_for(@arrangement) do |f| %>

    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :date, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.text_field :date, :class => 'input-large datepicker' %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :timeslot, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= collection_select(:arrangement, :timeslot_id, @available_timeslots, :id, :timeslot_spelled) %>
        </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Controller

```
# GET /arrangements/new
  # GET /arrangements/new.json
  def new
    date = Time.now.to_date.to_s(:db)
    @arrangement = Arrangement.new
    @available_timeslots = Timeslot.where("location_id = ? AND date(timeslot) = ? AND arrangement_id is null", current_user.user_details.location_id, date).order('timeslot ASC')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @arrangement }
    end
  end

# POST /arrangements
  # POST /arrangements.json
  def create
    @arrangement = Arrangement.new(params[:arrangement])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @arrangement.save
        # update the timslot record with the arrangement id
        if @timeslot = Timeslot.update(@arrangement.timeslot_id, :arrangement_id => @arrangement.id)
            format.html { redirect_to @arrangement, notice: 'Arrangement was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @arrangement, status: :created, location: @arrangement }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @arrangement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @arrangement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error given is referring to @available_timeslots being empty when trying to save the form

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.

```rb
def new
  @available_timeslots = ...
  if @available_timeslots.count > 0
    flash.now[:error] = "nil errrraaarrr"
  end

  ...
end
```

In view

```rb
<div class="controls">
  <%- if @available_timeslots.count > 0 %>
    <%= collection_select(:arrangement, :timeslot_id, @available_timeslots, :id, :timeslot_spelled) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= flash.now[:error] %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work in my case because the collection_select is updated ajaxily based on the date they choose. I don't want an error message to appear until they choose a date, i just want the dropdown to be blank as it is currently.

Comment: I see. I would try to find seek a jquery solution to this problem since error handling on client side would avoid that error.

Answer (score 0):

`@available_timeslots` is nil. Make sure it's set with an array of available timeslots to avoid this error message.

Comment: That's why i asked this question. I know it's nil, but how can i show a nice error when the form is submitted without it being filled in.

Comment: you can check it with .blank? or with .nil? in your controller side. And easily can flash the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to add `@available_timeslots = []` in the else clause

```
def create
    @arrangement = Arrangement.new(params[:arrangement])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @arrangement.save
        # update the timslot record with the arrangement id
        if @timeslot = Timeslot.update(@arrangement.timeslot_id, :arrangement_id => @arrangement.id)
            format.html { redirect_to @arrangement, notice: 'Arrangement was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @arrangement, status: :created, location: @arrangement }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @arrangement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      else

        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @arrangement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```